# When mounting a AzureFile K8S volume, I get a "azureMount: SmbGlobalMapping failed" error

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm trying to mount an `azureFile` volume on a Windows K8S pod, but I get the error

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azure-file-share" : azureMount:
>   SmbGlobalMapping failed: fork/exec
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe: The
>   parameter is incorrect., only SMB mount is supported now, output: ""

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue where was a bad `azurestorageaccountkey` value in the secret. You can have a secret like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: volume-azurefile-storage-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: <base 64 encoded account name>
  azurestorageaccountkey: <base 64 encoded account key>
```

What was throwing me was that Azure already base 64 encodes the account key, and it was not clear if you need to double encode it for this secret file.

The answer is yes, you do double encode it. If you do not, you get the error from the question.